# Find position of a word in a string

Tags: vb.net, string

I have to implement a search in following method,

Let :

```
Dim checkin As String = "This is the base string, i have to find a word here"
Dim valueSearch  As String="to find a word"
```

Now the algorithm to be implemented is:

- Dim str() As String = Split(checkin , " ")
- Dim Position As Integer
- `Position`=Find Position of `str(0)` in the string
- Check `str(1)` with the next word after `position`th word in `checkin`
- if not equal continue the second step with `str(1)`
- `if  Dim valueSearch  As String="to find a game" then`
  i have to display a message that `"to find a"` is present

My question is that is it possible to find the position of a word in a string using

[string.Contains()](http://vb.net-informations.com/string/vb.net_String_Contains.htm) operation. or any other possibility to implement this algorithm?

Comment: String.Contains(), INSTR or IndexOf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this

Create recursive Method. Use String.Contains. Its true then return else continue the method.

```
   private Sub Recursive(ByVal xStr As String, ByVal xSearch As String)

           If xStr.Contains(xSearch) Then
                MsgBox(xSearch)
            ElseIf xSearch.Contains(" ") Then
                Recursive(xStr, xSearch.Substring(0, xSearch.LastIndexOf(" ")))
            Else
                MsgBox("Not Founded")
            End If

        End Sub

 Call Recursive("This is the base string, i have to find a word here", 
 "to find a game")
```

Answer (score 0):

String.Contains(), INSTR or IndexOf should all do what you want

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y7ddk24.aspx